# Count restart from 0 after exceeding n times the limit

Tags: javascript

I want to reset a count value to **0** after reaching a certain limit. And return the value which is (originalCount - limit).

I have tried `if` and `for` loops but cannot achieve what I want.

```
//payload is an array of bytes//
if (payload[0] == 33) {
    result.PayloadTtype = 'Vehicle Count';
    if (payload[2] > 80) {
        payload[2] -= 80; //Sensor Reboot due to exceeding limit
        result.Count = payload[2];
    }else {
        result.Count = payload[2];
    }
}
```

I can return correct values up to **159** but once it exceeds **160** on wards it prints `(80,81....)`. I want it to start again from **0** even for multiples of `80n (n = 1,2,3...)`.

Comment: what's wrong with `payload[2] = 0;` ?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I think he wants a kind of circularity, and `90` should evaluate to `10`, not `0`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I can make payload[2] = 0; but that will only print 0. I want to reset it to 0 and start counting from there again. And can anyone tell me how to use markdown while adding a comment?

Comment: @Hemanth In comments `\`asd\`` creates code formatting (`asd`), `*asd*` or `_asd_` creates italic (*asd*), `[title](url)` creates link ([title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657996/count-restart-from-0-after-exceeding-n-times-the-limit/)) and finally `**asd**` and `__asd__` creates bold (__asd__). You can test [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the modulus of `payload[2]` by `80`:

```js
if (payload[0] == 33) {
    result.PayloadTtype = 'Vehicle Count';
    if (payload[2] > 80) {
        payload[2] %= 80; //Sensor Reboot due to exceeding limit
        result.Count = payload[2];
    }else {
        result.Count = payload[2];
    }
}
```

You can also move the unconditional statement (the assignment of `result.Count`) out of the `if` statement, in which case you don't even need the `if` (modulus will leave values smaller than `80` intact):

```js
if (payload[0] == 33) {
    result.PayloadTtype = 'Vehicle Count';
    payload[2] %= 80;
    result.Count = payload[2];
}
```

And if you really wanted to make things compact, you can even do this (though it harms readability in my opinion):

```js
if (payload[0] == 33) {
    result.PayloadTtype = 'Vehicle Count';
    result.Count = payload[2] %= 80;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Both the ways work for me.

Comment: sure did not recognize the tick mark was for that. I have one more query how can I retain the leading zeros while converting from any to binary. I looked up at several solutions not what I want. I'm decoding date from the payload and I cannot pad zeros manually.

Comment: To store leading zeros, you have to convert the number to string. If you can use ES2017, then use [`String#padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), like `number.toString().padStart(2/*expected length*/, 0)`. Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)!